# Where to modify existing oracle job interval

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am able to see oracle jobs detail in **user_jobs** table . Now I want to modify the job interval. Is this the correct oracle table where I need to update the job interval or is  there is any other table or package which would help to change a already existing job in oracle db.

I have done some research , but I could n't find exactly where to update.

Comment: Unrelated but: are you aware that `dbms_job` is deprecated? You should use `dbms_scheduler` for new things.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, strange when you create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`, then Oracle creates automatically a `JOB` for refreshing.

Comment: @Wernfried: yes I know. And those jobs are really complicated to handle. For one you have no idea what went wrong when the MView doesn't refresh. We stopped using `refresh next` and are using exclusively `dbms_scheduler` to call `dbms_mview.refresh` to get a decent error logging and monitoring for that. Oracle probably can't change that anymore (just as they can't remove the deprecated and annoying `LONG` columns in their system tables)

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't update the `user_jobs` table, to amend a database job you need to run something like this

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE (
   name         =>  'update_sales',
   attribute    =>  'repeat_interval',
   value        =>  'freq=weekly; byday=wed');
END;
/
```

full details are here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12392

Comment: That will change a **scheduler** job which would be present in `user_scheduler_jobs`, but Midhun is talking about `user_jobs` which are something different.

Answer (score 0):

All job modifications should be done using DBMS_JOB. You're in need of [DBMS_JOB.CHANGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#i1000622).

Comment: Minor note: after updating your job you have to issue `COMMIT;` otherwise it will not become effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Package Procedure DBMS_JOB.CHANGE